# Create a jar with only delta files between two jars

Tags: java, jar

I have two jars (say A.jar and B.jar having some files . 
I want to create a third jar( say c.jar)  which only contains the files that are there in B.jar but not in A.jar.
Is there a java API for doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: You want to do it using Java code? Or in a script using for instance the `jar` command?

Comment: Think this will help you. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Comment: @aioobe In Java Code. The JAR only contains audio , images and xml. There are no java files in the jar . I don't need to check the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of an API, but you can use [japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker) or [pkgdiff](https://github.com/lvc/pkgdiff) to find the differences in the jars, unzip them and make a jar from the missing classes.